# Cumulative counting number of occurrences of integers in MATLAB array including zero occurences

Tags: matlab, classification

I am constructing a classification tree in MATLAB, however I have too many features and I want to select the right set of features to maximize my accuracy. To do that, I have a brute-force algorithm that tries all possible subsets of features (e.g. if my data has 4 features, I would try selecting features (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2,1)...; (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4) etc., and if for a given subset of features, my accuracy is above 84%, I want to save the feature numbers that was used.

So what I would like to do is have an array that can count the number of occurrences of each feature number for each feature set that produced an accuracy above 84%. This array would also have to be cumulative over all iterations of feature combinations.

I've seen other posts for counting integer occurrences in Matlab arrays, but for me a) the size of the array to be analyzed changes throughout execution and b) if there are no occurrences of a number, I want the counting array to display 0 in its place.

For example, if I have two feature subsets [1 2 7] and [1 3 6 8] I would like my counting array to be
[2 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0] (assuming I have ten features total)

Comment: [histcounts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)

Comment: @beaker I tried histcounts but I can’t seem to force it to show zeros for “empty buckets”, and when I try to add results from two different results of different array sizes it seems to automatically change the bucket sizes and widths... I’m not sure if I’m using it correctly though

Comment: Never mind! I think it will work if I specify the bin edges.

Comment: When you ask a question, you should always show what you've tried. That way, random people won't come by and suggest things you've already tried and won't have to use mental telepathy to determine exactly where your attempts went wrong.